# Image labelling, How to annotate a picture which don't have an object but i should have its xml file as i explained in the question

Tags: image, yolo, white-labelling, yolov5, yolov4

I find a dataset which some of the pictures is not annotated but it has like this format in xml.
[image: annotated picture with out object]

But this another picture has an annotated object which look like this:
[image: It hase an object which is annotated]

Can any one tell me How and by which tools i can annotated a picture which don't have an annotated object but i should have its xml file as you can see in first image.

Comment: It's very hard to parse a *picture* of XML and imagine what it will look like on an image we don't have, especially without any idea of what sort of annotation you are expecting, or what tools you normally use. If you want folks to help you, make it easy for them.

Comment: I want to have YOLO format, as you know it needs text format, So i found in that dataset which some pictures are not annotated, I shocked how they creat such a XML file, I tried with Labelimg annotation tool, but i couldnt, One another quistion Do we need a picture for yolo training wich not contain any object in it.